# move pattern in file over one column if match awk

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, scripting

I have looked for an anwser but came up short, if i know the right direction to head that would be helpful.

heres the problem .   I have a file. with the following inside. each codeblock should be a new line

```
nisNetgroupTriple: (,USER,)
cn:example
nisNetgroupTriple: (,USER,)
nisNetgroupTriple: (,USER,)
```

I wish i want to be able to move the first column over to the second column if the pattern is present. like below

```
nisNetgroupTriple: (,USER,)
                 *cn:example
nisNetgroupTriple: (,USER,)
nisNetgroupTriple: (,USER,)
```

I could deal with the rest I believe but wanted to also perform a command within the values enclosed in the `(,,)`   such as the value `USER`, such as then running `ldapsearch` to pull the cn of the associated USERID values.

I know this is a simple task in itself. but wanted to automate it.

Thank You.

Comment: What pattern are you trying to match? Is it `cn:`?

Comment: the entire line matching "cn: NAME*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk '/^cn:/ { $2 = "*"$1; $1 = "\t"} 1' input_file > output_file
```

`$2 = "*"$1` copies the first field to the second field, with an asterisk before it. `$1 = "\t"` replaces the first field with a tab, to get the indentation (you could also use a bunch of spaces if you prefer).